# Where is autorun in Linux(Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bittorrent, autorun

I have the machine with Ubuntu desktop 7.something  ... I want some server-like behavior without my participation. For example I have Azureus torrent-client there and I want it to start with the system like a service. Is it possible or I need another torrent-client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is that a program that relies on a GUI can typically only start after GUI login, unless the app is smart enough to be able to run headless and then display the GUI later (very few apps can do this<strike>, and I doubt Azureus can</strike> EDIT: Azureus actually can do this, I have linked to instructions for doing so below). <strike>If you need it to be a GUI app, then your best bet is to [start the app with your Gnome session](http://library.gnome.org/users/user-guide/stable/prefs-sessions.html.en).</strike>

Otherwise, as Jonik mentions, you can add a line to /etc/rc.local that starts the program - anything that you can run from a command line which does not rely on X11 or Gnome should run from rc.local with no trouble.

Edit:

Your best bet is [The headless swing UI](http://wiki.vuze.com/w/HeadlessSwingUiHowTo), which would give the best of both worlds, starting headless before you log in and making the GUI available later when you request it. Try either the screen or daemonized method, depending on which you are more comfortable with.

[Another option is to start Azureus headless](http://wiki.vuze.com/w/Console_UI#Headless_operation_using_the_Console_UI_.28and_Web_UI.29), you could also do this from rc.local. You could use the [Azureus telnet UI](http://wiki.vuze.com/w/TelnetUI), and then connect to it latter from the shell, if you are comfortable controlling the app from the command line.

Answer (score 3):

To automatically run a command (that e.g. launches some service) when the system starts, an easy way is to add it in `/etc/rc.local` file.

A more flexible (but not as simple) way is to create an init script under `/etc/init.d/`. Packaged Ubuntu server software comes with such scripts. To learn more, you could start [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto).